# Set size of tab in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, size, jtabbedpane

Is there any way to change size of **tab** in `JTabbedPane`?  I mean not all panel but only the small tab that user has to click to see what is under it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either create your own `TabbedPaneUI`, but it might be simpler if you just use the `JTabbedPane#setTabComponentAt` and use a larger component for rendering the tab title

Answer (score 8):

this is worked for me.

```
 JLabel lab = new JLabel();
 lab.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
 jTabbedPane1.setTabComponentAt(0, lab);  // tab index, jLabel
```

or try this change to all tab component in same sizes (called in main method)

`UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab.contentMargins", new Insets(10, 100, 0, 0));`

Answer (score 3):

In order to create custom tabbedPane, I recommand to check the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/zipfiles/components-TabComponentsDemoProject.zip). You have to create your own panel, then you can modify the Component that render the title. Finally you use`setTabComponentAt` to put your own panel in the pane.